# After updating node 10, .d.ts files did not generate in project

Tags: typescript

I am working in a typescript project. After updating my node version to **10.16.3**, I am unable to generate .d.ts files during my compilation process. If I downgraded to node 8, it was working fine.

Please find my ts.config.json and package.json details below,

**ts.config.json**

`{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "amd",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitUseStrict": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators" : true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,

    "types": ["jasmine","jasmine-ajax","requirejs","chai","es6-promise"]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "public",
    "coverage",
    "test-report"

  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}`

**package.json**

    `"dependencies": {
      "browser-sync": "2.11.2",
      "canteen": "*",
      "es6-promise": "3.2.1",
      "fs-extra": "3.0.1",
      "ghooks": "^1.2.1",
      "glob": "^7.0.5",
      "gulp": "^3.9.0",
      "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.0",
      "gulp-gzip": "^1.4.0",
      "gulp-jscpd": "0.0.7",
      "gulp-jshint-xml-file-reporter": "^0.5.1",
      "gulp-jsoncombine": "^1.0.3",
      "gulp-print": "^2.0.1",
      "gulp-protractor": "^4.1.0",
      "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
      "gulp-s3-upload": "1.6.6",
      "gulp-sass": "^4.0.1",
      "gulp-sass-lint": "^1.1.1",
      "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.2.0",
      "gulp-svgmin": "^1.2.4",
      "gulp-tslint": "^7.0.1",
      "gulp-typedoc": "^2.0.0",
      "gulp-typescript": "^2.13.0",
      "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
      "gulp-unzip": "^1.0.0",
      "gulp-zip": "^4.0.0",
      "highlight.js": "9.14.2",
      "htmllint": "^0.6.0",
      "jasmine-ajax": "^3.2.0",
      "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
      "jasmine-json-test-reporter": "^1.0.0-beta",
      "json-assert": "^1.0.2",
      "karma": "^0.13.2",
      "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
      "karma-coverage": "^0.5.5",
      "karma-firefox-launcher": "^0.1.7",
      "karma-generic-preprocessor": "^1.1.0",
      "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.2.2",
      "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.6",
      "karma-jasmine-ajax": "^0.1.13",
      "karma-requirejs": "^0.2.6",
      "karma-typescript": "^3.0.12",
      "markdown-spellcheck": "^0.11.0",
      "markdownlint": "^0.3.1",
      "md-2-json": "^1.0.2",
      "nedb": "^1.8.0",
      "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
      "pix-diff": "^2.0.0",
      "pluralize": "^3.0.0",
      "protractor": "5.3.2",
      "public-ip": "^2.3.5",
      "require-dir": "^0.3.2",
      "requirejs": "^2.2.0",
      "rimraf": "^2.6.1",
      "rollup": "0.52.3",
      "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "8.3.0",
      "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "3.0.3",
      "rollup-plugin-sourcemaps": "0.4.2",
      "rollup-plugin-uglify": "2.0.1",
      "rollup-plugin-uglify-es": "0.0.1",
      "run-sequence": "^1.0.2",
      "sass-lint": "1.12.1",
      "shelljs": "^0.7.0",
      "simple-git": "^1.43.0",
      "simple-odata-server": "^0.2.0",
      "tableify": "^1.0.1",
      "through2": "^2.0.1",
      "tslint": "4.0.2",
      "tslint-microsoft-contrib": "^4.0.0",
      "typedoc": "^0.12.0",
      "typescript": "3.0.3",
      "typo-js": "^1.0.1",
      "uglify-js": "3.2.2",
      "webpack": "2.5.1",
      "webpack-stream": "^3.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^3.4.28",
    "@types/es6-promise": "0.0.28",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.9",
    "@types/jasmine-ajax": "^3.1.27",
    "@types/requirejs": "^2.1.26"
  },`

Can anyone guide me to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give us your `package.json`, `tsconfig.json`, and your module bundler config (like `webpack.config.js`) thx.

Comment: I have added my configuration. Please those things.